# how to achieve uniform scroll experience on mobile safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I've found a few results about this problem but none solving the problem for screens that have content shorter and taller than screen height.

In short, i have a layout like this:

```
---------------------
|    fixed header    |
---------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|       content      |
|                    |
|                    |
......................
```

1. header needs to be fixed so when scrolling content, header should be visible all the time.
2. if there is less content than content element height, content element should stretch to the bottom of the screen and no scrolling should be possible (currently, if scrolled quickly, extra gaps appear at the bottom).
3. (most interesting part) when mobile safari shows/hides/expands/contracts its UI elements (address bar, bottom tools bars) scroll should behave "normal" (i know its hard to describe, but currently elements get weird offsets).

I've read its related to using `vh` units, but even if i don't use them at all and use percentages, it still behaves weird when safari expands/contracts viewport size when scrolling.

Question is - is there some css-only solution to have consistent vertical scroll experience on mobile safari?

PS.
If web app is added to homescreen, thus opening in full screen, all works as expected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
    }

    body {
      font-size: 12px;
      background: red;
    }

    #root {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .page-wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .navigation__wrapper {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      margin: 0;
      z-index: 3;
      font-size: 19px;
      padding: 0 15px;
      height: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background: blue;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .content__wrapper {
      background: #fff;
      min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="navigation__wrapper">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="content__wrapper">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When Safari shows/hides it's UI bars, height of the available space is changed. To prevent re-rendering all the layout on each frame during the animation of UI bars appearing/hiding, screen size is discrete and changes only on the end of UI animation. So neither percent or vh units will be recalculated during process

Comment: ok, but could that result in extra gaps at the end of the content? (regardless at what point of time)

Comment: Elianski i've added the code. Its simplified version (from react app) but same problem in mobile safari.